# Blazor EditForm goes over MainLayout when scrolling

Tags: scroll, blazor, always-on-top, webassembly, blazor-editform

I have this Blazor WASM with a MainLayout top with a logo and other things. On a child form I have an Editform this work OK, but when I scroll the page the EditForm scrolls on top of the MainForm instead of under. The other content in the child scroll fine under.
Any ideas?
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say MainForm - do you mean the top bar on the screen? If so, go into your site.css and add `z-index:9999;` to your .main .top-row section. it should look similar to this:

```
.main {
    flex: 1;
}

.main .top-row {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d5d5;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    **z-index: 9999;**
}

    .main .top-row > a, .main .top-row .btn-link {
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin-left: 1.5rem;
    }

.main .top-row a:first-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: The stars around z-index are simply to highlight where it should go

Comment: Thanks a bundle. That worked like a charm after I forced a reload:-) Thanks again:-)

Comment: Happy to help! I suppose as well it would be worth noting that if for some reason you want a component to render above the login bar, you would have to set that component's z-index to be greater than the top-row one, however, I can't seem to think of a scenario where that would be desired :)